# Problem authenticating APIs with Passport in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

I've followed the official Laravel docs for installing passport but authentication is failing. Specifically, i'm consuming my API with JS as shown in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript. I've checked the cookies and 'laravel_token' is being passed once I login but for some reason the final authentication fails. I created two other test projects and the results are the same. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. My requests weren't passing the csrf_token as instructed here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript under csrf protection.